# Execute GRASS command within QGIS python console

Tags: qgis, python, grass-gis

We try to calculate catchments with the `r.water.outlet` function from python console. To do so we use the following code:

```
import processing
rlayer = QgsRasterLayer("/my/path/DrainageDirection.tif", "DrainageDirection")
processing.runalg("grass:r.water.outlet", rlayer , 2621378.611131 ,1262320.888212, "2589700, 2640500, 1242200, 1270000", 73, "/my/path/zzz.tif")
```

The result in the `zzz.tif` file is only one pixel with no value. This result differs when running the `r.water.outlet` is called from the GRASS Tools GUI.

So, three questions:

1) Do we handle the input raster (rlayer) correct?
2) Do we handle the output raster correct?
3) Would it be possible to read a GRASS Mapset raster directly from python console?